# Display powershell output as a stream in electron-react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, powershell, electron, child-process

I want to run some powershell commands and stream (that cli command takes some time and prints few line as the process proceeds) its output in react(i use electron and its configured)

i tried this but its not a stream, it just prints all lines altogether. the actualy output will print line by line

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process")
exec("spicetify apply", { shell: "powershell.exe" }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use `exec`, because it won't call your event handler with the process' output until *after* the process has terminated, i.e. it will *not* stream; use `spawn` instead.
- You don't need to involve a shell in order to call an external executable with arguments; you only need to call via a shell if you need *shell features* such as output redirection (`>`), which is not the case here. Not calling via a shell speeds up your command, which is especially noticeable with `powershell.exe`, whose startup cost is nontrivial.

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process")
let child = spawn("spicetify", [ "apply" ])
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString()))
```

Comment: how do i display it in react ui?

Comment: @RaghavanVidhyasagar, I'm not familiar with React, but `data.ToString()` contains a line of stdout output every time the event fires (which answers your question as asked). If you have a question about React in the context of an Electron, I suggest asking a _new_ question.